# Why all parking lights and DRL stopped working on Odyssey 2012?

Tags: honda, lights, tail-lights, odyssey

My car failed safety inspection because the license plate lights were out.

When I was replacing the bulbs, I noticed that all parking lights and daylight running lights are not working either. In addition, the brake lights stays off when I turn on parking lights, but when I press brake pedal, they turn on. Reverse lights work fine without any issue.

A Honda dealer failed the safety inspection, and was asking $50 to replace license plate lights. Since it is a lot, and I could do it myself easily, I told him that I won't take his offer.

I have LED bulbs for license plate lights, and normally they work a long time. I am very surprised that there is a sudden failure of several bulbs.

I checked many fuses, but they all seem to be fine. The dash lights work fine too, and as expected. My hunch is that the dealer unplugged something because he was not happy that I did not let him overcharge for a small repair.

**Vehicle information:** Honda Odyssey 2012 EXL

Comment: The brake lights sound like they are functioning correctly.

Comment: @SolarMike Yes. Brake lights have two levels. Dimmer level does not turn on with parking lights, but brighter level turns on, when brake pedal is pressed.

Comment: The dealer's not going to waste time unplugging something out of spite off an inspection.

Comment: @narkeleptk I hope that too. What do you think would have failed which caused all parking lights to stop working?

Comment: Check your fuses

Comment: Does your car have a buzzer to warn you that the lights are on when you open the door?  If so, is it working?

Comment: @Moab I checked several fuses and they all appear to be fine.

Comment: @HandyHowie The buzzer is working, both when lights are on _parking_ and _on_ settings, but not when on _auto_ setting.

Comment: If you have the owners manual it will show fuses and relays that are for DRL and parking lights, sometimes there are multiple fuses and relays. It could be a bad multifunction switch also.

Comment: @Moab I checked many fuses including for DRL (which I replaced too) and small lights. Could not find one specifically for parking lights. There are four different places fuses are. Switch can be the cause, as it appears to be one single thing failing. Where is the switch and how can I troubleshoot it?

Comment: its on the steering column>>>>>https://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/honda,2012,odyssey,3.5l+v6,1502552,electrical-switch+&+relay,headlamp+switch,4472

Comment: @Moab If you are talking about ignition switch, it is working fine.